# Assigning multiple text flags to an observation

Tags: r, validation, dplyr

I have some temperature data. I want to write a simple QA/QC script that will look through it and flag (in the QA/QC sense) data requiring verification/manual checking. I want it to essentially append flags to the existing column without creating a whole new column for each individual flag. I have a way to do it but it is inelegant. Is there a cleaner way to be doing this?

```
d<-data.frame(time=1:20, temp=c(1:5,-60,7:10,NA,12:15,160,17:20))
```

`time` is merely sequential observations and `temp` is some fictitious temperature data.

```
d$Flag[is.na(d$temp)]<-"MISSING" #flag the missing data
d$Flag[d$temp>120&!is.na(d$temp)]<-paste(d$Flag[d$temp>120&!is.na(d$temp)],"High",sep="_") #flag data beyond a threshold
d$Flag[d$temp<(-40)&!is.na(d$temp)]<-paste(d$Flag[d$temp<(-40)&!is.na(d$temp)],"Low",sep="_") #flag data below a threshold
dtIdx<-which(abs(diff(d$temp,lag=1))>10) #set an index vector of changes >10 based on first derivative
d$Flag[dtIdx]<-paste(d$Flag[dtIdx],"D10",sep="_") #select data and paste in new codes 
d$Flag<-gsub("NA_","",d$Flag) #strip NA that is introduced to flags
```

This creates the variable `Flag` and then sequentially overwrites it with itself + new information from each new condition. It works, but it feels messy. I also don't like having to clean the NAs that are introduced - can I ignore them from the outset somehow?

Comment: If you defined `d$Flag<-""` at the start, it avoids the need to clean up the NA at the end.

Comment: Yep, I had tried that by setting it to ```NULL``` which didn't work... didn't occur to me to set it to ```""```. That solves part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using `tidyverse`. For `dtIdx`, I temporarily create a new column with that information, then I create the `Flag` column with the other designations (i.e., `MISSING`, `High`, and `Low`) using `case_when`. Then, I `unite` the two columns ignoring `NA` and also drop `dtIdx`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(
    dtIdx = ifelse(c(abs(diff(temp, lag = 1)) > 10, FALSE), "D10", NA),
    Flag = case_when(is.na(temp) ~ "MISSING",
                     temp > 120 ~ "High",
                     temp < -40 ~ "Low")) %>%
  unite(
    "Flag",
    c(dtIdx, Flag),
    sep = "_",
    remove = TRUE,
    na.rm = TRUE
  )
```

**Output**

```
   time temp     Flag
1     1    1         
2     2    2         
3     3    3         
4     4    4         
5     5    5      D10
6     6  -60  D10_Low
7     7    7         
8     8    8         
9     9    9         
10   10   10         
11   11   NA  MISSING
12   12   12         
13   13   13         
14   14   14         
15   15   15      D10
16   16  160 D10_High
17   17   17         
18   18   18         
19   19   19         
20   20   20
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(
  time = 1:20,
  temp = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,-60, 7, 8,
           9, 10, NA, 12, 13, 14, 15, 160, 17, 18, 19, 20)
),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,-20L))
```

Comment: Ok, I was thinking this would likely involve mutate and unite somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can abstract out a function from the procedure you use. Something like this

```
flag <- function(..., init, sep = "_") {
  trimws(Reduce(
    \(x, y) replace(x, y[[1L]], paste(x[y[[1L]]], y[[2L]], sep = sep)), 
    list(...), init = init
  ), "left", sep)
}
```

Then apply it like this

```
d$Flag <- flag(
  list(is.na(d$temp), "MISSING"), 
  list(which(d$temp > 120), "High"), 
  list(which(d$temp < -40), "Low"), 
  list(which(abs(diff(d$temp, lag = 1)) > 10), "D10"), 
  init = character(nrow(d))
)
```

Output

```
   time temp     Flag
1     1    1         
2     2    2         
3     3    3         
4     4    4         
5     5    5      D10
6     6  -60  Low_D10
7     7    7         
8     8    8         
9     9    9         
10   10   10         
11   11   NA  MISSING
12   12   12         
13   13   13         
14   14   14         
15   15   15      D10
16   16  160 High_D10
17   17   17         
18   18   18         
19   19   19         
20   20   20
```

---

Or use `factor` with `interaction`.

```
na_as <- forcats::fct_explicit_na
DEFAULT <- ""
d$Flag <- trimws(whitespace = "_", interaction(sep = "_", 
  factor(is.na(d$temp), labels = c(DEFAULT, "MISSING")), 
  na_as(factor(findInterval(d$temp, c(-40, 120)), labels = c("Low", DEFAULT, "High")), DEFAULT), 
  na_as(factor(abs(c(diff(d$temp, lag = 1), NA)) > 10, labels = c(DEFAULT, "D10")), DEFAULT)
))
```

You get the same output as above.